# Using powershell to re-link Tenable Nessus Agent

Tags: powershell, nessus

I have several, systems (MS OS) that have the Tenable Nessus agent installed in my environment. I am attempting to re-link the agent to the management portal via PowerShell. I will be using SCCM to execute, the script so I created a simple PS script with one line of code that will execute the script remotely on the workstation. I can execute the script locally using powershell no problem, on errors, and the Nessus agent re-links.

I am sure, I am overlooking something. Here is my script

```
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus 
    Agent\nessuscli.exe' -ArgumentList 'agent link -- 
    key=<License Key> -- 
    host=<hosted portal here> --port=<port>' -Passthru -NoNewWindow
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This topic can be closed. I have since addressed the issue.

Comment: How did you address the issue, if you don't mind me asking.  Running into the same issue here.

Comment: Not at all, this is what worked for me and ran this as a script in SCCM. I would recommend signing  your code against a certificate, in the environment I ran this one we required our code to be signed.

`Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus Agent\nessuscli.exe' -ArgumentList 'agent link --key= YOUR KEY HERE --host="<linktoportal>" --port=<port>' -Passthrough -NoNewWindow`

Comment: I ran this as a script against one of my global collections in SCCM